# rediccionar segun ID de link html

Tags: html, href

teniendo lo siguiente:

```
<li aria-haspopup="true"><a id="data" href="#" data-href="estrategico" class="slide-item acciones">Objetivos Estratégicos</a></li>
<li aria-haspopup="true"><a id="data" href="#" data-href="especifico" class="slide-item acciones">Objetivos Especificos</a></li>
```

Donde los data-href son los identificadores para acceso a otra url.

Tengo esta funcion, que supuestamente deberia capturar el valor a enviar:

```
$(document).on('click','#data', function(e) {

e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();

var data = $(this).data('href');
$.ajax({
    method: 'get',
    url: '/creacion/',
    data: data,
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data){
      
    }
});
});
```

lo que necesito es capturar en otro archivo php, estrategico o especifico segun el menu seleccionado.
alguna orientacion sobre como poder realizar esto?

Comment: Estás leyendo mal los atributos. debes usar `var data = $(this).attr('data-href');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede ser que el id duplicado este causando conflictos

Asumiendo que usas jQuery puedes cambiar el `id="data"` a `class="... data"` y usar el siguiente código:

```
$('.data').on('click', function(e) {

e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();

var data = $(this).data('href');
alert(data);
});
```

Esto obtiene el valor que hay en data-href del elemento al que le den clic

Comment: estimado, gracias por responder. Efectivamente ahora puedo capturar el valor del data-href. Ahora bien, necesito redireccionar a otro archivo con ese valor. Lo puedo con ajax o hay alguna otra forma de lograr eso? Por ejemplo, necesito que rediccione a archivo.php con el valor de data-href y poder procesarlo

Comment: finalmente lo pude solucionar y tu ayuda me sirvio de orientacion para hacerlo. muchas gracias. saludos.

Comment: Que bueno que te sirvió la orientación, disculpa que no haya contestado antes.